# window scroll in not working with if else if

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm using the `scroll` function, but the code in my `else if` blocks do not appear to be executing.

I'm trying to hide one div and show another, once the user scrolls past a certain point.

Here's my code - what am I doing wrong?

```js
var scrolTop = $('.content').offset().top;
var showOneHeight = $('.showOne').height();
var showTwoHeight2 = $('.showTwo').height();
var showThreeHeight3 = $('.showThree').height();
var showFourHeight4 = $('.showFour').height();
var offSetValue = scrolTop + (showOneHeight - 50);
var offSetValue2 = scrolTop + (showTwoHeight2 - 50);
var offSetValue3 = scrolTop + (showThreeHeight3 - 50);
var offSetValue4 = scrolTop + (showFourHeight4 - 50);
// alert(offSetValue3)
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var height = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (height > offSetValue) {
    $('.showOne').fadeOut();
    $('.showTwo').fadeIn('slow');
  } else if (height > offSetValue2) {
    $('.showOne').fadeOut();
    $('.showTwo').fadeOut();
    $('.showThree').fadeIn('slow');
  } else if (height > offSetValue3) {
    $('.showOne').fadeOut();
    $('.showTwo').fadeOut();
    $('.showThree').fadeOut();
    $('.showFour').fadeIn();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.contentArea {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.boxes {
  width: 50%;
}

.pinned {
  background: rgb(72, 91, 35);
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-family: system-ui;
  color: #fff;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  display: none;
}

.showOne {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height: 500px; background: violet;"></div>
<div style="height: 500px; background:yellowgreen;"></div>
<div class="contentArea">
  <div class="pinned boxes">
    <h1>i am pinned side</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content boxes">
    <div class="box showOne">
      <strong>paragraph one</strong>
      <p>i am a paragraph. i have more text then a heading mostly too lines i have.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box showTwo">
      <strong>paragraph two</strong>
      <p>i am a paragraph. i have more text then a heading mostly too lines i have.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box showThree">
      <strong>paragraph three</strong>
      <p>i am a paragraph. i have more text then a heading mostly too lines i have.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box showFour">
      <strong>paragraph three</strong>
      <p>i am a paragraph. i have more text then a heading mostly too lines i have.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="test" style="height: 500px; background: rgb(39, 96, 106);"></div>
<div style="height: 500px; background: rgb(46, 35, 46);"></div>
```

Comment: no actually i like to work with but have some issue with else if

Comment: Someone fixed your link to jQuery.  Can you use more words to describe what you need done now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  if (height > offSetValue) {
    $('.showOne').fadeOut();
    $('.showTwo').fadeIn('slow');
  } else if (height > offSetValue2) {
    $('.showOne').fadeOut();
    $('.showTwo').fadeOut();
    $('.showThree').fadeIn('slow');
  } else if (height > offSetValue3) {
    $('.showOne').fadeOut();
    $('.showTwo').fadeOut();
    $('.showThree').fadeOut();
    $('.showFour').fadeIn();
  }
```

The problem is the else if conditions. The else if is not executed because the first condition is ever true when the second and third is true.

You need to specify the range beetween heights are really true:

```
if ( (height > offSetValue) && (height < offSetValue2)) {
     //exec
} 
else if ( (height > offSetValue2) && (height < offSetValue3)) {
   //exec
}
else if (height > offSetValue3) {
  // exec
}
```

This resolve the problems whit if/else if (Y)

Edit 1:

Try this for confirm:

```
var scrolTop = $('.content').offset().top;
var showOneHeight = $('.showOne').height();
var showTwoHeight2 = $('.showTwo').height();
var showThreeHeight3 = $('.showThree').height();
var showFourHeight4 = $('.showFour').height();
var offSetValue = scrolTop + 500;
var offSetValue2 = scrolTop + 700; 
var offSetValue3 = scrolTop + 900;
var offSetValue4 = scrolTop + 1100;


$(window).scroll(function() {
  var height = $(window).scrollTop();

  if ( (height > offSetValue) && (height < offSetValue2)) {
    console.log(1)
    $('.showOne').fadeOut();
    $('.showTwo').fadeIn('slow');
    $('.showThree').fadeOut();
    $('.showFour').fadeOut();
  } else if ( (height > offSetValue2) && (height < offSetValue3)) { 
    console.log(2)
    $('.showOne').fadeOut();
    $('.showTwo').fadeOut();
    $('.showThree').fadeIn('slow');
    $('.showFour').fadeOut();
  } else if (height > offSetValue3) {
    console.log(3)
    $('.showOne').fadeOut();
    $('.showTwo').fadeOut();
    $('.showThree').fadeOut('slow');
  }
});
```

Comment: You tried to scroll whit cursor and not whit the mouse wheel? i think the gap beetween the box are less for trigger all else if right. I tried many time and it work fine now.

Comment: i tried with increased some more gap between trigger but still its not working.  can you please put a code inside condition statement?

Comment: I have edited the answer whit an example (Edit 1). The example have static values for trigger the change and you can see from the console log the 1/2/3 values when the else if are triggered.

Comment: thank you very much dear. it's really help me a lot <3

Comment: No prob dear (Y) <3